# how to insert data into an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone please help me with some code to insert data into an existing array of objects so i have this array

```
[
  {
    "order_id": "241918",
    "customer_name": "Marietjie",
    "customer_surname": "Short",
    "total_items": "44",
    "completed_items": "17",
    "percent_complete": 0.38636363636364,
    "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "joel"
  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
    "customer_surname": "Hodge",
    "total_items": "16",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 0,
    "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": null
  }
]
```

i want to insert data from this array into the array above to replace the value of the `percent_completed` with the value of the array below.

```
["17", "0"]
```

so for the first

Comment: You could create a new array with the modified values using map:  `const newArray = a1.map((item,index)=>({...item,percent_complete:a2[index]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 var array=[
  {
    "order_id": "241918",
    "customer_name": "Marietjie",
    "customer_surname": "Short",
    "total_items": "44",
    "completed_items": "17",
    "percent_complete": 0.38636363636364,
    "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "joel"
  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
    "customer_surname": "Hodge",
    "total_items": "16",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 0,
    "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": null
  }
]

var array2=["17", "0"];

for(var x=0; x< array.length; x++){
 array[x].percent_complete=array2[x]
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate your original data array and overwrite it's property with according value from the provided update array. Something like this:

```
var data = [
  {
    "order_id": "241918",
    "customer_name": "Marietjie",
    "customer_surname": "Short",
    "total_items": "44",
    "completed_items": "17",
    "percent_complete": 0.38636363636364,
    "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:0-0",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "joel"
  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
    "customer_surname": "Hodge",
    "total_items": "16",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 0,
    "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": null
  }
];
var update = ["17", "0"];
data.forEach((d, i) => {
  data[i].percent_completed = update[i]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array containing the new values and the one containing the datas (Loop will stops when the end of one of them will be reached), then update the data one at each iteration.

```js
let myarr = [
  {
    "order_id": "241918",
    "customer_name": "Marietjie",
    "customer_surname": "Short",
    "total_items": "44",
    "completed_items": "17",
    "percent_complete": 0.38636363636364,
    "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "joel"
  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
    "customer_surname": "Hodge",
    "total_items": "16",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 0,
    "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": null
  }
];

let newvals = ["17", "0"];

for (let i = 0; i < newvals.length && i < myarr.length; ++i)
  myarr[i].percent_complete = newvals[i];

console.log(myarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const array =[
  {
    "order_id": "241918",
    "customer_name": "Marietjie",
    "customer_surname": "Short",
    "total_items": "44",
    "completed_items": "17",
    "percent_complete": 0.38636363636364,
    "datetime_received": "2018-07-25 15:18:25",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": "joel"
  },
  {
    "order_id": "281774",
    "customer_name": "Ashleigh",
    "customer_surname": "Hodge",
    "total_items": "16",
    "completed_items": "0",
    "percent_complete": 0,
    "datetime_received": "2018-10-04 15:59:19",
    "delivery_date": "2018-10-29",
    "delivery_from": "12:00",
    "delivery_to": "13:00",
    "completed": "0",
    "shopper": null
  }
];
const array1= ["17","12"];

result = array1.map((value, index) => {

return { ...array[index], completed_items: value };
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: if you mutate something then you should not use `map`, instead use `forEach` to make it clear this code is not pure and has side effects.

Comment: Fixed.. @HMR Thanks